# AWS Load Balancer - change region (with Terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elb

I have a Terraform module that provisions an Auto-Scaling group and all the necessary infrastructure to support it on AWS. Usually, Terraform is quite good at detecting changes in the infrastructure code. 
However, today I noticed that, **if Terraform is managing a load-balancer, a change in the region will lead to an error.**

I constructed a minimal example to replicate the error (this example requires a valid AWS profile)

```
# =========================================================================================
#                 PROVIDER

provider "aws" {
  region  = "${var.aws-region}"
  profile = "${var.aws-profile}"
}

# =========================================================================================
#                 VARIABLES

variable "aws-region" {
  description = "The AWS region"
  type        = "string"
  default = "eu-west-3"
}

variable "aws-profile" {
  description = "The name of the AWS shared credentials account."
  type        = "string"
}

# =========================================================================================
#                 LOAD BALANCER

resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name                       = "load-balancer"
  internal                   = false
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  enable_deletion_protection = false
  subnets                    = ["${aws_subnet.subnet-1.id}", "${aws_subnet.subnet-2.id}"]

}

# =========================================================================================
#                 NETWORKING

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block        = "10.0.0.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${var.aws-region}a"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-2" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${var.aws-region}b"
}


resource "aws_internet_gateway" "ig" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}
```

To replicate the error:

- 1) run `terraform init; terraform apply`
- 2) change the region
- 3) repeat step 1) which will lead to an error

The error is as follows:

> Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:
>   * module.asg-local.aws_lb.alb: 1 error(s) occurred:
>   * module.asg-local.aws_lb.alb: aws_lb.alb: Error retrieving ALB:
>   ValidationError:
>   'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:199344973012:loadbalancer/app/rafa-lizzie-alb/ccbf16e255c2f904'
>   is not a valid load balancer ARN status code: 400, request id:
>   8b28f0d8-2ec2-11e9-896a-4ffb7ae94bb8

I know that it is not very normal to change regions, but in any case, it might happen, right?
I would also like to know if this is the expected behaviour from Terraform, or if this is a bug.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is not the behaviour for every resource that is looked up by the ARN and the ARN includes the region. I'm not really sure how Terraform should handle that really as it's a pretty fair assumption to say that things should fail if you try to switch to a different region than your state file has things in like this.

Comment: While this question is an interesting one I don't think it's really answerable on StackOverflow and it should probably lead to a longer conversation with the Terraform AWS provider maintainers where you have raised this as an issue: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7517

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a good fit for StackOverflow and works better as an issue on GitHub instead where the OP has already posted it: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7517

Comment: yes, I agree with @ydaetskcoR, this question has pretty much been answered, even thought it still raises questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior. What's happening is that when you run plan/apply, all the resources will try to "refresh" its state. Since you've changed provider region, it is not able to retrieve the resource (wrong region) to "refresh" the state.

You can bypass this behavior by basically passing "-refresh=false" to plan and apply runs.